# Solutions of $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know a function $u(x,y)$ other than $(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$ and 0 that satisfies 
the equation $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u^3.$$

Comment: The tag [tag:differential-equations] is intended for questions about ordinary differential equations, there is a separate tag for [tag:pde]s; see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for solutions $u=u(x)$, so that the equation becomes $$u''=u^3.$$ By phase-plane analysis, you get infinitely many solutions lying on the orbits $$2(u')^2 = u^4+C,$$ as $C \in \mathbb{R}$.